# Display overlay to cover whole page

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, overlay

I have a web app which is loading within an `iframe`. I need to display an overlay div to cover the whole page.
The problem is that the overlay is currently displaying only in the `iframe` area and not covering the whole page,
(Our application (a child application) is part of a set of applications loading in `iframe`)

Comment: `#overlay {position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; background: black; opacity: 0.5;}`

Comment: To cover the whole window you have to create the overlay div in the original windows dom not the iframe.

Comment: @ThomasStachl Yes its correct, we need to do it in the original window DOM, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay
{

  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: .3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  -moz-opacity: .3;
   z-index: 101;
}
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7adq/)**

Comment: This solution will only cover the iframe area if called from within the iframe, not the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="EN">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html 
{
 overflow: auto;
}

html, body, div, iframe 
{
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px; 
 height: 100%; 
 border: none;
}

iframe 
{
 display: block; 
 width: 100%; 
 border: none; 
 overflow-y: auto; 
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="tree" name="myiframe" src="http://www.your_page.com/" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you may use JavaScript like;

```
<script type="Text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function resize_iframe()
{
    var height=window.innerWidth;//Firefox
    if (document.body.clientHeight)
    {
        height=document.body.clientHeight;//IE
    }
    //resize the iframe according to the size of the
    //window (all these should be on the same line)
    document.getElementById("cam").style.height=parseInt(height-
    document.getElementById("cam").offsetTop-8)+"px";
}

// this will resize the iframe every
// time you change the size of the window.
window.onresize=resize_iframe; 

//Instead of using this you can use: 
//  <BODY onresize="resize_iframe()">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="cam" width="100%" scrolling="yes" src="http://www.your_page.com" onload="resize_iframe()">
</iframe>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.