# Creating a cover page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, my question is, if I have Jquery, how would I go about adding a cover page or entry page to my site?

If that's too vague, say I want to enter my site but I don't want to enter directly to the content of my home page.  I want an image and a text box showing saying 'enter' and then when clicked, the image disappears allowing access to my index.asp.  How would I go about something like this?

Comment: The question is still a bit vague. You can show pop ups with jquery in a variety of ways. One is jqueryui dialog. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display overlay to cover whole page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121885/display-overlay-to-cover-whole-page)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a div over the first page, and that would be hidden when user clicks the 'enter' button:

On a js file:

```
function EnterSite() {
    document.getElementById("welcome-div").hide();
}
```

On the html file

```
<div id="welcome-div">
    This is the welcome page
</div>

<button onclick="EnterSite()"></button>
```

The function could also be set with event listener on another js file, there are several ways of doing it.